# Slingshot in box2d and libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, drag

How can I achieve something like this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnpkd3Ucg7s

I know it should be done with a MouseJoint. The only problem is that I don't know how to "pin" the MouseJoint to the starting point. Everthing else I will manage to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy to create a mouse joint, check up this youtube tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF5dUiJtYng

And check up the source for the video you provided

http://appcodingeasy.com/Gideros-Mobile/Gideros--Box2d-Slingshot

Comment: I know how to create a mouse joint but I don't how to pin the initial position,drag the object and release

Comment: The pin & drag is made by the mousejoint.